# Hide Docker Run Command in Docker Build Output

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm having a problem where a password is being shown when I run a docker build command. This is because the Dockerfile contains a curl command that uses a username and password to authenticate the command, like this:

```
=> CACHED [stage-0  7/15] RUN curl -u "<Username>:<Password>" ...  0.0s
```

I tried rerouting the output of the curl to /dev/null like this:

```
cmd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But that only hides output from the curl command not the actual command itself.

Comment: I don't have Docker working right now to test (one day they'll fix all their issues with Apple Silicon...) but have you tried using an [env file or build secrets?](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/)

Comment: It's worse than that: the username and password are persisted in the image in plain text, so anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially extract them from the image's `docker history` and maybe it's even being automatically published on Docker Hub if you've pushed a public image there.  Can you run the `curl` command outside Docker entirely, so the Dockerfile doesn't need access to these credentials at all?